# Quicktime on iPhone

Tags: iphone, quicktime

May I know if the videos played via quicktime through safari are saved in the iPhone? If they are may I know where to find them?

Answer (score 0):

They're not saved. streamed, buffered of roughly a  maximum 15 minutes and scrubbed. It wouldn't be possible to saved them as watching one streamed tv program would be 200meg. Saving this amount of information every time you watch a program would be unfair to the user as they would run out of space in a day.

Comment: Not to mention also that applications are sandboxes so that your programs can't access the data of others.